# Is $\lim_{x\to a}f(2x)$ equal to $\lim_{x\to a} 2f(x) $?

Tags: limits

> When doing limit such as $\lim_{x\to a}f(2x)$, does this equal to  $\lim_{x\to a} 2f(x) $?
>
> If they are equal, can you make a proof about it? If we can't do this, then why?

Thank you very much

Comment: Not necessarily equal.  Consider $f(x)=x^2$ and $a=2$

Comment: Try this on a constant function, such as $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Perhaps there is a mistake in the Question.  Did you mean to ask if $\lim_{x\to a}f(2x)$ was equal to $\lim_{x\to 2a}f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you at least have to ask for continuity, then instead of $2$ use $k$, there is no reason for that to happen, just think that what you are saying it´s the same as "zooming in" or "zooming out" a function centered on $a$ by a constant $k$ and then having the same function for some reason.

Comment: This could be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I´m new here and I can´t comment until 50 points of something